# What is the shortest path from $(-2,0)$ to $(2,0)$ that does not cross the unit circle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> What could be the shortest path and distance to go from $A$ to $B$, provided that path should not cut the unit circle?
>
> [image]

Tried by taking tangents of circle but could not get solution.

Comment: What do you mean by intersect the circle? Normally a tangent would be said to intersect the circle.

Comment: Sir, Path should not cut through the circle. it can touch the circle.

Comment: Round the circular arc or tangentially from A to the y axis and back to B. Either way, you are touching the circle.

Comment: Follow the tangent from $A$ to its touching point, then along an arc to the touching point of the tangent from $B$, then along that tangent to $B$?

Comment: One walking on the path should not go inside the circle anywhere.

Comment: Is not the length $2\sqrt 3+\pi/3$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You go from $A$ to the circle at the point it is tangent, around the circle, and leave the circle when the tangent goes through $B$.  To find the points of tangency, use the fact that for a circle the tangent is perpendicular to the radius at that point.  A diagram is below.  The line segments are tangent to the circle at $D,F$

[image]

Comment: Nice! [+1] Nevertheless, I have the feeling that the proof is not rigorous enough: this path looks intuitively the shortest, but how to prove so?

Comment: @Dr.Mathva:  We know the straight line is the shortest distance between two points, so it must be straight from $A$ to the circle, around the circle, and straight to $B$.  You can compute the length as a function of the angle where the line touches the circle and minimize it.

Comment: thanks Ross sir, i'll try to write.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Ross Millikan's answer, note that the hypotenuse $AE$ is twice the leg $AF$, so $AFE$ is a 30-60-90 triangle.